# What is this .gtkrc file?

Tags: gnome, gtk

I was going through Tim Pope's [dotfiles](https://github.com/tpope/tpope) and I happened to notice that he had a `.gtkrc` file. What does this configuration file do? And how can I make one of those?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.gtkrc` is the configuration file for [Gtk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtk), the GUI library used by [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) applications and others. Gtk 1.x programs read `~/.gtkrc`; Gtk 2.x programs read `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.

The Gnome settings program may have created one of these files for you. If it hasn't, you can create one yourself. There is some documentation of the syntax and options in the [Gtk developer manual, under “resource files”](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/gtk2-Resource-Files.html).

Answer (score 4):

GTK themes use `gtkrc` (GTK run commands) files to configure the appearance of the different widgets. GTK will load multiple `gtkrc` files, loading some after others to allow settings to be predictably overridden.

Normally, the user `gtkrc` file is `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, but your distribution may use a different file. To determine if you distribution uses a separate file, open up `.gtkrc-2.0` in a text editor and look for a comment such as:

```
Do Not Modify This File
```

If a line such as this is present, another file will be specified. The file specified is then what you will need to modify.

For most distributions, if `~/.gtkrc-2.0` does not exist, simply create a plain text file with this path and name.

Comment: basically, in unix you can always edit files in your home directory and nothing that bad will happen. If something goes wrong you can just delete or rename it, and the system will read the default settings which are placed under /etc/