# Gtk2 Themes under Gentoo's Gnome 3

Tags: gentoo, gnome3, gtk, theme

I have made it to get a nice gnome shell environment running under my new gentoo. It's all fine, except there are a whole bunch of programs built against gtk2 (Chromium, Pidgin, Thunderbird, Firefox), and they look strangely out of place. The ui of the gtk2 parts looks rather like windows 95 than gnome 3.

I have not yet found out how to configure the controls and icons. The instructions found on the gnome theme sites seemed to be ignored by my gentoo system or were made for Ubuntu.

Any help?

Comment: [Tried a `.gtkrc-2.0` file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25043/11539)

Comment: That one I was looking for worked, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the hint from [sr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11539/sr), it was quite easy to solve this. I just chose my current gtk3 theme and linked it:

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc .gtkrc-2.0
```

And then my gtk2 ui's looked nice again.